# Sed match between commas in CSV

Tags: regex, sed

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
metadata,metadata,somevalue: a1;,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: b;,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: c;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: d*;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: e*4; f; g;,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: h;i;j*a,,,,,,
```

I want to replace everything for the columns that contain a `*` with something like `DATAREMOVED`

For the above example, the output would be like this:

```
metadata,metadata,somevalue: a1,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: b;,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: c;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,
```

I've tried something like this: `sed 's/,.*?\*.*?;/DATAREMOVED/g'` but it keeps grabbing from the first `,` to the first `,` after the match, which doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: sed doesn't support non-greedy... regex features vary between different tools, see... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y ... if your regex is correct, you can use `perl -pe <regex>` .. or use `[^,]*` instead of non-greedy

Comment: also, it is not necessary to post your actual input, create a small and simple sample that others can easily understand

Comment: Hey Sundeep, Your solution was the best, if you want to reply as a top level comment and I can select it as a solution. I used the following to get the matches: `[^,]*\*[^,]*`

Comment: there is already an answer with that solution, please mark that as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

I'm assuming your *expected output* is missing the following semi-colon, so this solution includes it.

```
metadata,metadata,somevalue: a1;,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: b;,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: c;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,
                               ^
```

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CG9Wyr/1)

```
[^,]*\*[^,]*
```

Replacement: `DATAREMOVED`

---

### Results

#### Input

```
metadata,metadata,somevalue: a1;,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: b;,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: c;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: d*;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: e*4; f; g;,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: h;i;j*a,,,,,,
```

#### Output

```
metadata,metadata,somevalue: a1;,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: b;,,,,,,,,,,,,,somevalue: c;,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,,,,,,DATAREMOVED,,,,,,
```

---

### Explanation

- `[^,]*` Match any character not present in the set (any character except comma) any number of times
- `\*` Match a literal asterisk character `*`
- `[^,]*` Match any character not present in the set (any character except comma) any number of times

Answer (score 0):

Linq can help.

```
public string ReplaceStar(string input)
{
    var outputArray = input.Split(',').Select(subStr => subStr.Contains('*') ? "DATAREMOVED" : subStr).ToList();
    return string.Join(",", outputArray);
}
```

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: My answer is in C#

Comment: FYI C# isn't sed

Answer (score 0):

Using awk, you can set the input Field Separator with your pattern and the Output Field Separator with 'DATAREMOVED':

```
awk -F'[^,*]*\\*[^,]*' -v OFS='DATAREMOVED' '{$1=$1}1' yourfile
```

`$1=$1` is only here to force the record to be updated with the new field separator.